# Agora Video SDK - Where exactly do I pass the HTTP verification code?

Tags: agora.io

I would like to know if I am putting the authentication code in the correct place since it is not entirely clear on the guide. I would like to know exactly where to put the HTTP authentication code. Furthermore, I would also like to know how the authentication ID can be inputted into the "agora auth" string (do I have to input it manually?) Thank you.

```
<string name="agora_app_id">""</string>
<string name="agora_auth"><Request.Builder request = new Request.Builder()
                String plainCredentials = "";
                String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredentials.getBytes()));>
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
</string>
```

This is in my string_configs.xml file, in values folder. The errors are:
Line 1: Element string must be declared
Line 2: Multiple root tags
Line 2: There should be a space between attribute and previous attribute for "new", = expected between new and request

Answer (score 0):

For the first line, you need to pass in your app id. Here's a guide on how to get your app id: https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/token#a-name--appidause-an-app-id-for-authentication

For the second line, you need to pass in the following string "customerId:customerCertificate" (without the quotes and fill in the string with your own customer id and customer certificate)